# Largest palindrome in a string

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge, palindrome

I am working on a question in which I need to find a largest palindrome given a string. [Here](http://stevekrenzel.com/articles/longest-palnidrome) is the description.

```
public class LargestPalindrome {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Longest Palindrome 1: " +findLongestPalindrome("xyzracecar"));  
    System.out.println("Longest Palindrome 2: " +findLongestPalindrome("abcexcbaddd"));
    System.out.println("Longest Palindrome 3: " +findLongestPalindrome("cacxx"));
  }

  public static String findLongestPalindrome(String str) {
    String palindrome = ""; // initializing empty string

    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
      for(int j = str.length(); j>i; j--) {
       String data = str.substring(i, j);
        if(isPalindrome(data)) {
          if(data.length() > palindrome.length()) {
            palindrome = data;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return palindrome;
  }

  /**
   * This method is used to check whether a given string is palindrome or not
   * 
   */
  public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    int last = s.length() - 1;

    for(int i=0; i<s.length()/2; i++) {
      if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(last)) {
        return false;
      }
      last--;
    }

    return true;  
  }
}
```

The code is working fine. Can it be optimized anymore?

Comment: Source of the challenge?

Comment: @Legato I have added it in my question. Not sure whether it can be categorized as source. Sorry for missing it earlier.

Comment: Quick comment: You need proper unit testing. :)

Answer (score 2):

Two minor points on the code and one on unit test:

1. **Combining `if` clauses**

   You can combine both `if` clauses as such:

   ```
   if (isPalindrome(current) && current.length() > palindrome.length()) { ... }
   ```
2. **Enhancing use of `for` loop**

   [Multiple local variables can be declared](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) in the `for` loop, so you can include your `last` variable as such:

   ```
   private static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
       for (int i = 0, last = s.length() - 1; i < s.length() / 2; i++, last--) {
           if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(last)) {
               return false;
           }
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```
3. **Unit testing**

   As mentioned in my comment, it will be better to turn your `main()` code into a series of unit tests to ensure your logic is working correctly. The example below uses [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) and [Hamcrest matchers](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial), and is meant to be a simple showcase for how this can be done. You should consider a variety of tests (e.g. empty `String`s, non-palindromic inputs) to also ensure it works for as many cases as possible. That is when you can consider some of the features of TestNG such as parameterized testing.

   ```
   @Test
   public void doTest() {
       assertThat(findLongestPalindrome("xyzracecar"), equalTo("racecar"));
       assertThat(findLongestPalindrome("abcexcbaddd"), equalTo("ddd"));
       assertThat(findLongestPalindrome("cacxx"), equalTo("cac"));
   }
   ```

*Bonus*: Oh yeah, is it the largest or longest palindrome you are looking for? Since you are dealing with `String`s, my suggestion is to be consistent and stick with permutations of 'longest palindrome'. :)

Answer (score 1):

h.j.k.'s answer is good, but I will build on it a bit.

1. `main`

   As others have said, use a testing framework to test instead of this! There is nothing *wrong* here, it's just that testing frameworks are better and a great tool for your programming tool belt. I'd also at least add some tests for `isPalindrome` like `assert isPalindrome("racecar")` and `assert !isPalindrome("foobar")`
2. `findLongestPalindrome`

   It's true that those if clauses can be combined, but instead of combining them let's look at what's going on.

   1. We're making a substring (`String data = str.substring(i, j)`)
   2. We're seeing if it's a palindrome (`isPalindrome(data)`)
   3. If it's longer then we make it the one we're considering returning `(if(data.length() > palindrome.length()) { palindrome = data; }`)

   Checking is something is a palindrome with `isPalindrome` is \$O(n/2)\$ which isn't terrible, but we're only saving it if it's longer than the current one we have, and we can know if it's going to be longer *before* we know if it's a palindrome by putting `data.length() > palindrome.length()` before `isPalindrome(data)`. So long as you use `&&` instead of `&` java will use short circuit evaluation and not do `isPalindrome(data)`.

   ***But!*** An even better way is to do `if (j - i > palindrome.length())` before you even make the substring and see if it's a palindrome.
3. `isPalindrome`

   This is fine as far as I can tell *(with h.j.k.'s suggestions of course)*, I might consider changing `last` to `j` or `i` to `first` or something so it's consistently named.

Comment: Good catch on doing the length check first!